# Unchecked cast when casting an object of type Any? into a lambda in kotlin

Tags: lambda, kotlin

My code works as intended but I am curious on why the following warning exists:

[image: cast Any! to lambda]

Is it safe to ignore the warning?
I know that Kotlin can't check erased types at runtime, but isn't Any the most generic (toplevel) object in Kotlin.

What am I'm looking for is a way to check if an object is of type "lambda".
Btw: Any? -> Any? does not get rid of the problem either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JVM provides you only with the raw type at runtime, e.g. `java.lang.List` instead of `java.lang.List<String>`. This also applies to kotlin lambdas: When you write `(Any?) -> Unit` in kotlin, it gets translated to the JVM type `kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1<java.lang.Object, kotlin.Unit>`.

Now, you have an object of type `Any?`. You can write `Any? as? Function1<*, *>` without any problems. You can also use `as` instead of `as?`, but risk a `ClassCastException` to be thrown.

But now comes the problem: The type `(Any?) -> Unit` and `(Int) -> String` are different types at compile time, but only because of their generic type arguments. At runtime, both are instances of `Function1`, which is why the compiler will issue a warning when you cast it to anything with generic arguments other than `*`.

> Is it safe to ignore the warning?

If you know what you are doing - Yes, it's just the limitation of the Java language. If you can rely on the type being what you expect it there is no error, however you will not get any exception if the generic arguments are different than what you expect.

If you don't know what you are doing, e.g. getting the parameter from code that you can't control - take this warning serious.

Comment: Thanks for such a clear explanation. I control the code and I expect to fixAUd to always be a lambda expression (or, in the worst case, null)

Comment: @feresr But if it's always a lambda or null, why do you need the cast after all?

Comment: To be able to invoke it, I'm implementing an interface and the parameter fixAUd is of type Any?, can't change that. All I can do is to make sure to always pass a lambda as a parameter.